# How to receive POST data from a .NET script

Tags: php, .net, post

I am working with a company who has made a script to send over POST data to my PHP script (which is all setup and port forwarded properly etc).

The problem is, they say my script is not set up to handle POST requests.

This is their script:

Try

```
        strPost = strPost.Trim.Replace(" ", "%20")



        Dim objRequest As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(strPostURL)

        objRequest.Method = "POST"

        objRequest.ContentLength = strPost.Length

        objRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"



        Try

            myWriter = New StreamWriter(objRequest.GetRequestStream())

            myWriter.Write(strPost)

        Catch eg As Exception



        Finally

            myWriter.Close()

        End Try



        Dim objResponse As HttpWebResponse = objRequest.GetResponse()

        Dim sr As StreamReader

        sr = New StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream())

        success = sr.ReadToEnd()

        sr.Close()



        success = "Post Successful"



    Catch ex As Exception

        success = ex.ToString

    End Try
```

And here is mine:

```
<?PHP

$website = $_POST['web'] ;
$name = $_POST['name'] ;
$tel = $_POST['tel'] ;
$town = $_POST['town'] ;

foreach($_POST as $key => $thisOne){
$out .= $key . ': ' . $thisOne ;
}
if($out)
mail('test@test.com', 'Test', $out) ;
?>
```

I am unsure of what they mean by my script is not set up to handle POST data, as $_POST is the right thing to use no?

---

Thanks for your reply, that is what I thought, but he is adimant that my script is faulty.

This is the error he says he is getting:

[image: .NET error]

---

He is telling me he still gets that error and:

The code we use works with Sales Force, Sage and 7 other custom CRM integrations we have previously done.

:(

---

Thanks, I found http://apikitchen.com/ allows me to properly test it and it's coming back fine. Thanks for your help! Must be him like you say.

---

He is now telling me he is getting a new error!

[image]

---

He has just sent me the following, can anyone with .NET experience see anything wrong with the code?:

```
Try
strPost = "name=lf&town=london&country=uk&web=www.lf.com&tel=0123456789&keywords=sales&pages=5&multivisit=multihitdt=2012/04/30%2014:31referrer=google&landing=home"

        strPost = strPost.Trim.Replace(" ", "%20")



        Dim objRequest As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://mysite.dyndns-remote.com/myscript.php")

        objRequest.Method = "POST"

        objRequest.ContentLength = strPost.Length

        objRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"



        Try

            myWriter = New StreamWriter(objRequest.GetRequestStream())

            myWriter.Write("name=lf&town=london&country=uk&web=www.lf.com&tel=0123456789&keywords=sales&pages=5&multivisit=multihitdt=2012/04/30%2014:31referrer=google&landing=home")

        Catch eg As Exception



        Finally

            myWriter.Close()

        End Try



        Dim objResponse As HttpWebResponse = objRequest.GetResponse()

        Dim sr As StreamReader

        sr = New StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream())

        success = sr.ReadToEnd()

        sr.Close()



        success = "Post Successful"



    Catch ex As Exception

        success = ex.ToString

    End Try
```

Comment: An Http POST is an Http POST regardless of how is generated on the client - curl, asp.net, java, python.  So use what your normally would use on the receiving PHP side of things.

Comment: As Kris said there should be no difference in data received, its all HTTP in the end. I'd suggest trying something like fiddler to analyze the request being sent to check that things are being sent correctly and that you are looking for the right variable names and then setting up a php test page to submit the same data to your endpoint to see if you can do that successfully. Between these two debug techniques I think you should be able to see where the problem is exactly.

Comment: Do var_dump($_POST) in the beginning of Your script where You receive the POST from .NET and paste it here - maybe vBasic is somehow "renaming" the POST parameters (I wouldn't be surprised).

Comment: If he's getting an error like that then the fault is all his - somehow he is not passing the right URI format `HttpWebRequest` object. Exactly the URI is empty, as the error says - so he should enter the valid URI for the VB script to run properly...

Comment: In reply to your latest edit: It is really his fault. He's getting an exception before he's even able to send data to your script! A person that calls himself a .NET developer should really be able to read and understand exceptions...

Comment: For your latest edit, the exception is still on the `WebRequest.Create` call.  The code you have posted, however : `Dim objRequest As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://mysite.dyndns-remote.com/myscript.php")` compiles and runs fine so he must be doing something other than what he has sent you.  We need to see the actual code to know what it going on.

Comment: Tell him to post the real code - this is not the call to `fncPost`. The new error means that he doesn't provide a proper URI. We need the real code. That is: Code that calls the `fncPost` method and the code of the `fncPost` method itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URI he's passing to the web request doesn't seem to be valid (the Exception says it is empty). This is the `strPostURL` parameter in the last line of the stack trace image you've shown here.

Tell him to use a proper URL when calling `SalesForcePost.fncPost` and everything should be fine.

This is in no way your fault and doesn't have anything to do with you not handling POST correctly. It is his fault. Tell him so, and if he doesn't believe you, send him here to show us some code.

**EDIT**
As for the new error: Same thing here. He's not passing a valid URI string. This may be because he's passing something like "htt://sometest.com" oder "http:/sometest.com". We can't help you any further unless you post all code necessary to see how the `fncPost` method is called and most of the code of the `fncPost` method - at least the part where he creates the web request.

The code you've posted is not his real code, otherwise he would not be getting the "URI scheme not valid" exception.

Comment: This.  He's failing to create `objRequest` and therefore also failing to send any `POST` data at all.

Comment: Doesn't the line: Dim objRequest As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(strPostURL)
Do that? (I know hardly anything about .NET btw)

Comment: Yes, but he's passing some invalid URL (probably an empty string) in the `strPostURL` parameter. So he's getting an exception, as the web request "doesn't know where to send to". The earliest point for the exception is the line you quoted, the latest point is when getting the request stream and writing to it. The exception message, however, is pretty clear about what's going on and any proper .NET developer would know how to debug this.